# magento bundle product price type dropdown disabled

Tags: magento

Why in my store admin panel, the `price type` dropdown is disabled, I can enable it by removing the `disabled` attribute through the `console` or add custom script in one of its template. but this is dirty way.

what is causing this dropdown greyed out? how can I enable it in a cleaner way?

[image: screenshot]

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I can see that answer came a little bit later, but today I had same issue and here is solution:

When dropdown price type is greyed out, that means that you are using non-"default" attribute set for your bundle product.

In order to fix this issue, create install / upgrade script that will add "price_type" attribute to all attribute sets that bundle products will use in your system (something like this):

```
<?php

$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();

$attributeSetCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute_set_collection')->load();

$productEntityTypeId = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
    ->getResource()
    ->getEntityType()
    ->getId();

foreach ($attributeSetCollection as $id => $attributeSet) {
    $entityTypeId = $attributeSet->getEntityTypeId();

    if ($entityTypeId == $productEntityTypeId) {
        $this->addAttributeToSet($entityTypeId, $attributeSet->getAttributeSetId(), 'General', 'price_type', 200);
    }
}


$installer->endSetup();
```

After this script is executed, price_type will have relations to all attribute sets, and your select box will become enabled.

Please note that attribute will not be visible under attribute sets edit screen in admin, but this does not mean that it is not assigned.
If you take a look in table: eav_entity_attributem you should see relations.

I hope that this will resolve some of your issues.